# Bootstrap Dropdown in the Wrong Place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap but I don't know why the dropdown menu is in the middle-left.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="warga/delete/<?php echo $a->id;?>">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
```

Answer (score 52):

Wrap your code within `<div class="dropdown">` ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/229/))

```
<td>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="warga/delete/<?php echo $a->id;?>">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was copy and pasting some code around and the dropdown class was somehow left behind.